# В боевом режиме виснет сортировка по дате

Tags: mysql, join

В локале полный дамп базы - все летает. На хостинге висим в глушняк (504я).  На первый взгляд все "как всегда" но бьюсь 2й день. Все подвисает. Итак:

```
SELECT * FROM nt_order_info
INNER JOIN stb_pass sp ON j_user_id = customer_id
ORDER BY date_order ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

Одна таблица  nt_order_info 18к записей, другая stb_pass 56к. Не пустые таблицы, но не критичный размер-то. А вешает меня ORDER BY по дате. Без него чуть меньше секунды, тоже дофига, но сойдет.
Сама по себе таблица ( nt_order_info) без join с другой сортируется нормально, без тормозов излишних. Более того, по тому же customer_id присоединяю другую таблицу (occustomer, на 43к записей) с той же сортировкой ORDER BY date_order - летаем.  Ну и на последок - таблицы occustomer и stb_pass джойнятся (правда без сортировки, ибо дата осталась в первой таблице) тоже без проблем.

Что еще. Почитал статью про strait_join (https://habrahabr.ru/post/138163/) - не помогло. Пробовал обе сделать InnoDB или обе MyISAM - неа...

### Вот сами таблички:

```
CREATE TABLE `nt_order_info` (
  `id_order` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `button` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `id_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `call_time` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `question` text NOT NULL,
  `refer` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `utm` text NOT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_order`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18119 /*!40101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 */;


CREATE TABLE `stb_pass` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stb_login` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stb_password` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `j_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=70132 /*!40101 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 */;


 CREATE TABLE `occustomer` (
`customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`email` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`telephone` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`fax` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`password` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`salt` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`cart` text,
`wishlist` text,
`newsletter` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`address_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`customer_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`cid` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
`cid_added` datetime NOT NULL,
`iso_country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`character` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`comment` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=49421 /*!40101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 */;
```

---

Локал explain: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Боевой explain: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите (и заодно сравните с тестовой машиной) план выполения запроса (explain)

Comment: И почему в структуре таблиц нет foreign key ? Они как бы напрашиваются и ради них будут построены индексы, которые очень возможно помогут вашему запросу

Comment: Локал id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
SIMPLE
sp
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
50805
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1
SIMPLE
nt_order_info
ref
customer_id
customer_id
4
newrustv_n8298_tv.sp.j_user_id
1
NULL

Comment: Боевой 
id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
SIMPLE
nt_order_info
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
15949
Using temporary; Using filesort
1
SIMPLE
sp
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
60345
Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)

Comment: Видите SIMPLE nt_order_info ref поменялся на SIMPLE sp ALL? Значит джойн пошёл без индекса. Помножить на cpu 18k*56k - триллион сравнений и только потом сортировать - быстро это конечно не будет. Иначе говоря - где потеряли индекс при переносе схемы?

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! Потерял...блин, уже мозг "замылился"...

Comment: Очень странный план на локальной машине. как будто вы сортируете по полю из таблицы sp. А вообще было бы логично сначала взять 20 записей из nt_order_infoб а потом к ним подклеить sp. Но для этого все таки нужен индекс в таблице sp и наиболее правильно его сделать было бы создать foreign key